# Random sample of points to calculate K function on a large point set

Tags: point, error, spatial-statistics

For a point pattern analysis in R, I want to study a relatively large point dataset (about 1 million points) with a **cross K function** to compare different categories of points. Including a Montecarlo simulation for envelope, the calculation of K on this dataset is very intensive, and I would like to sample the data to be able to calculate it faster.

How can I estimate the error in the result of K if I take a random sample of points (e.g., 1% or 5% of the data)? Can it be derived mathematically or should I run a Montecarlo simulation to see how much the results differ?

Comment: With ArcGIs, with QGIS, with Python, with... ?

Comment: it's a question about geo-statistics, not about tools

Comment: Please read up on Point Pattern Analysis (PPA). It not valid to take a sample of a spatial point process as the underlying assumption of PPA statistics is that they do not represent a sample.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because this question is about spatial statistics concepts rather than specific tools in specific software.